# How to disable user input (including touch) on a web page

Tags: html, css

I have three buttons on my web page. On the click of one button, a process starts, and after a certain period of time, an alert will show "process complete".

How do I lock the screen from any further user input until that time?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be putting a `div` element on top of everything else, with a very high `z-index`.

```
<div id="blur"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#blur { position: fixed; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; top: 0px; 
        z-index: 999; display: none }
```

The `display: none` is so it doesn't show up right away. Use JavaScript or jQuery to change the `display` property to "block" (or use jQuery's `.show()`).

For further effect, you could give it a slightly transparent milky background:

```
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
```